# Регулярное выражения - JS

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

мне надо написать регулярное выражения на js для поиска ссылок, но не понимаю как сделать.

Условия

- Ссылка начинается с `http , https , /`
- Ссылка заканчивается `.png , .jpg , .gif` или символ пробела

И сразу говорю мне надо именно регулярку и - `$("img").src` - мне не нужен.

спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вы понимаете, насколько сложное в итоге может получиться регулярное выражение? Зачем вам это?

Comment: Ссылка `https://www.google.com/#.jpg` под ваши требования подходит?

Comment: В RFC 3986 есть [пример](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#appendix-B) простого выражения (не для валидации). Можете попробовать заменить в нём нужные группы захвата. Дать формально правильный ответ на ваш вопрос очень сложно

Comment: nomnoms12, любые символы, я нашёл похожое выражения но переработать его не могу -
`/(https?:\/\/|ftps?:\/\/|www\.)((?![.,?!;:()]*(\s|$))[^\s]){2,}/gim`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/(?:https?:\/\/|\/).*?(?:(?:\.gif|\.png|\.jpg)|(?=\s))/gim
```

https://regex101.com/r/RWbL1E/2